# How to use arrays to code whether the Roulette spin will land on Black or Red?

Tags: c#, arrays, roulette-wheel-selection

Hi I am making a C# Roulette wheel as part of a college project. I cannot seem to use arrays to program my Roulette wheel to recognise the Red or Black colours.

I used arrays to code the roulette ball to land on the numbers of the wheel, this works fine. I tried to use the same concept but with the two colours. This is what I have done so far:

```
int[] x = {213, 231, 250, 268, 285, 297, 310, 319, 324, 325, 326, 323, 315, 304, 291, 277, 260, 242, 223, 204, 183, 165, 147, 132, 120, 110, 102, 97, 98, 99, 104, 115, 126, 142, 158, 176, 194};
int[] y = {152, 153, 158, 165, 174, 185, 202, 219, 236, 254, 270, 293, 307, 322, 333, 348, 355, 361, 367, 364, 362, 357, 347, 338, 321, 307, 288, 269, 254, 234, 217, 201, 185, 174, 164, 160, 155};
string[] Number = { "0", "32", "15", "19", "4", "21", "2", "25", "17", "34", "6", "27", "13", "36", "11", "30", "8", "23", "10", "5", "24", "16", "33", "1", "20", "14", "31", "9", "22", "18", "29", "7", "28", "12", "35", "3", "26" };

string[] Red = { "32", "19", "21", "25", "34", "27", "36", "30", "23", "5", "16", "1", "14", "9", "18", "7", "12", "3" };
string[] Black = { "15", "4", "2", "17", "6", "13", "11", "8", "10", "24", "33", "20", "31", "22", "29", "28", "35", "26" };        

cboColour.Items.Add("Red");
cboColour.Items.Add("Black");

string guessColour = cboColour.Text;


if (position == ballPos && loopTimes == loopCount)             
{
    tmrRoll.Enabled = false;

    // Arrays (guessing)

    int arraypos = Array.IndexOf(Number, guess);

    int arrayRed = Array.IndexOf(Red, guessColour);
    int arrayBlack = Array.IndexOf(Black, guessColour);

    // Number + colour correct    
    if (ballPos == arraypos && ballPos == arrayBlack || ballPos == arraypos && ballPos == arrayRed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You guessed the number and the colour correctly!");
        addEarnings = currentBet * 35 + 10;
        totalGrapes = totalGrapes + addEarnings;              
    }
    // Only colour correct
    else if (ballPos != arraypos && ballPos == arrayBlack || ballPos != arraypos && ballPos == arrayRed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You guessed the colour correct!");
        addEarnings = currentBet + 10;
        totalGrapes = totalGrapes + addEarnings;
    }
    // Only Number correct
    if (ballPos == arraypos && ballPos != arrayBlack || ballPos == arraypos && ballPos != arrayRed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You guessed only the number correctly!");
        addEarnings = currentBet * 35;
        totalGrapes = totalGrapes + addEarnings;
    }
    // Nothing correct
    else if (ballPos != arraypos && ballPos != arrayEven || ballPos != arraypos && ballPos != arrayOdd)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have failed to guess the number or colour correctly.");                 
    }
}
```

Comment: So... whats the problem exactly? We need more than "It doesn't work"

Comment: I think you could simplify this quite a bit if you created a class to contain this information.  A class with a property for `number` and `color`.  Then you could just have one collection of these objects and randomly select one as your "spin"

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to tell us exactly what problem you're facing, as well as what you have tried to do to solve it.

Comment: `arrayPos` and `arrayBlack`/`arrayRed` are not going to be returning the same thing. `Array.IndexOf` returns the index of an element within an array. If the element you were searching for was, for example, 32, then `arrayPos` would be 1 while `arrayRed` would be 0. Since it's impossible for `ballPos` to be equal to both 1 and 0 at the same time, you will never get a situation in which the player guessed both the number and the color correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to do the work for you, so this will all be psuedo code, but it should lead you to finding the right path.

You do not want to get in the business of trying to keep related data in two different places.  This is a perfect time to use classes.  Imagine if you had a single object that contained all the properties of a single Roulette wheel instance.

Something like this:

```
class RouletteInstance
{
    //an integer representing the number

    //an enum representing the color
}
```

Then you had some collection of all the possible instances on a roulette wheel:

```
Collection<RouletteInstance> instances
```

Then you could "spin" the wheel by selecting a single instance at random from the collection.

From there you would check the randomly selected instance against the users input to see if its a match.

**Also**, keep in mind that a Roulette wheel has more than [two colors](https://www.casinoz.club/userfiles/Koleso1.jpg)...

Comment: And the wheels in America are different than those in Europe... http://www.roulette-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/american-vs-european-roulette.jpg

Comment: @RufusL I did not know that. Thank you!